# Has anyone successfully implemented Google cast sdk with Jetpack Compose? What approach did you take?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am currently trying to add Google cast sdk to a pure Compose app.

I have hit several issues with various approaches. I am wondering if anyone else has achieved this and if so what approach did they take?

I have tried adding the cast implementation at the Activity level and using flows and callbacks to communicate with composables. With this implementation I am stuck at being able to add the mini controller to the activity (single activity app) as it is a compose activity.

I tried adding the mini controller fragment the recommended compose way using AndroidViewBinding composable but it won't inflate using the recommended approach.

I even tried overriding the AndroidViewBinding composable and inflating manually which works to a certain extent but then I have issues with memory leaks.

I understand this is a very broad question so I'm just looking some general direction if someone has had success doing this and I'm happy to elaborate on what I've tried so far.